# UPDATE SET values WHERE data from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, set

```
UPDATE kid_progress_Backup
SET    level = 9 (column in kid_progress_Backup)
FROM   users1
WHERE birthyear_string = 01/01/2001 (column in users1)
```

So basically all the questions in this forum I have looked at were about setting one columns value = to the value in another column from another table. BUT mine is not. I want

```
kid_progress_Backup.level = 9 
IF
users1.birthyear_string = 01/01/2001
AND
kid_progress_Backup.level = 8 
IF
users1.birthyear_string = 01/01/2002
WHERE
id>270
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maintain one foreign key between two tables. In your case

```
kid_progress_Backup,users1 tables
```

Suppose `uid` is foreign key then you can write query as

```
UPDATE kid_progress_Backup
SET    level = '9' where uid In(Select uid from  users1
WHERE birthyear_string = '01/01/2001')
```

Comment: UPDATE kid_progress_Backup 
SET level = '10' where userid In(Select id from users1 WHERE birthyear_string = '01/01/1997') This works BUT how do I add a) SET level = 9 WHERE ... = birthyear_string = '01/01/1997' etc... ALSO WHERE id>270. Not too sure about where and how I write multiple SETS

Comment: I think u should execute same query twice.

Comment: If you look up IN you can see that it is not used for this. ie: I just did it and it updated ALL the records. ie: It updates all rows with the conditions stated with an IN. Oh dear.

Comment: But I did use it without the second condition and worked perfectly. Is there any way of getting a second condition to work but not in the way the In works rather how an INNER JOIN would work ie: it has to satisfy the 2 conditions.

Comment: UPDATE kid_progress_Backup a,users1 b SET a.level = '9' where a.uid=b.uid and b.birthyear_string = '01/01/2001';
UPDATE kid_progress_Backup a,users1 b SET a.level = '8' where a.uid=b.uid and b.birthyear_string = '01/01/2002';

Comment: You have been a big help. THANKS